# Calls to print() result in expected output being interpreted as zsh command

Tags: python, output, zsh

I have a text file that contains the introduction to a book from Project Gutenberg:

```
Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having
little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me
on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part
of the world.
...
```

I was using this `intro.txt` file to test out a module I am working on to parse strings and when testing found some unexpected behavior I cannot explain:

```
with open('intro.txt', 'r') as file:
    # strip newlines to get one string of text
    data = file.read().replace('\n', '')

print(data)
```

Results in terminal output:

```
zsh: command not found: Call
```

Similarly:

```
print(len(data))
```

Results in output:

```
zsh: command not found: 1092
```

Essentially, the first element of whatever is to be printed is being interpreted as a `zsh` command. This only happens when calling `print()`.

**Edit:** See comments for additional info. I have started fresh in a new venv and have not been able to reproduce the error. If I can determine what caused this behavior in my former venv, I will post this as an answer.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Maybe something changing your `print`?

Comment: How are you calling the script? Maybe you're doing it incorrectly, like `% $(tmp.py)` (where `%` indicates the Zsh prompt).

Comment: What if you write to a file or use `sys.stdout.write()`?

Comment: Similar to comment above. Maybe you run something like `./tmp.py`, but the script does not start with a shebang line. Then run like `python ./tmp.py` or add the shebang.

Comment: To be clear, I haven't gotten to the point of using this as a script yet, I have only been testing simple functionality within my IDE. If I write to a file instead of calling print(), everything functions as expected.

Comment: Any ideas what could be changing print() ?  I have recently used pip to install pytest to my venv

Comment: Still try with a shebang. Sounds like your IDE does not know your script is python, and runs it as zsh instead. Actually, I don't know how your IDE decides the file type. Did you save the script as a .py, or is not not even saved yet?

Comment: `print()` might be a valid zsh command...

Comment: The problem looks like it’s in the way you’re calling the code. How are you executing this? It looks like zsh is trying to execute your printed output. This isn’t a python problem but an issue in how you’re calling python.

Comment: When running from terminal: python3 <filename>.py 
Looking over my terminal history I see that single quotes are being added to my terminal commands such that the command becomes 'python3 <filename>.py'   I agree now this is a zsh problem and not a python problem.

Comment: @Keldorn If it were trying to run the Python script with Zsh, it'd error on `with`. What we're actually seeing is Zsh trying to run the *output* of the Python script.

Comment: @Ted Are you sure they're single quotes? They might be backticks, which would explain the error. Backticks are the old command substitution syntax.

Comment: Confirming they are single quotes and not backticks

Comment: `print()` is the *start* of a valid `zsh` function definition.